# Systemd Service does not start on reboot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, services, raspbian

I have the following systemd service called startupsh.service placed in `/etc/systemd/system/` on my raspberry pi running rasbpian.

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to start telegram bot
After=graphical.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/finder.sh &

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also enabled the service with

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable startupsh.service
```

And `sudo systemctl is-enabled startupsh.service` shows that the service is in fact enabled.
Furthermore, if I run `sudo systemctl start startupsh.service` everything is working as expected. However, if the pi gets rebooted the service does not execute and `sudo systemctl status startupsh.service` shows that the service is inactive (dead)

What is going wrong on startup? How can I fix thsi?

Edit: The finder.sh scripts looks as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Starting Bot..."
source /home/pi/Desktop/Airdropfinder/airdropfinderEnv/bin/activate
python /home/pi/Desktop/Airdropfinder/airdropfinder/src/telegrambot.py
```

Comment: 1) Why do you have the `&`? 2) What are the contents of the script? Is it actually suitable for Type=forking? 3) Do the system logs show that it at least *tried* to start the service, or do they show that there was no attempt at all?

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for your reply. I added the content of my finder.sh script to the post. I honestly don't now what the logs show. Where can I find does logs? I used the `&` because the python script that I am calling should be running "for ever".

Comment: You can access logging for this service with `journalctl -u startupsh.service`.  Also, I am not sure you should put the ampersand after the command.  The init for systemd has options for handling different styles of services, and you might be undermining it.  I suspect Type=simple might be what you want there.  If the service genuinely forks on its own and not with an ampersand, then Type=forking makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Restart=on-failure` to your systemd unit file.

[systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=)

> Restart=
>
> If set to on-failure, the service will be restarted when the process exits with a non-zero exit code

Comment: I have always and it doesnt work neither.